# vector-like input - numpy - typing

Tags: python, numpy, typing

I have a problem with python typing of the function with vector-like (1-D) input, which will be looped.
The input should be one of `list`, `tuple`, `numpy.ndarray` or similar.
What is important I will be checking the length for the input.
Thus the `typing.Sequence` should be perfectly suited. But is not as `np.array` is not a `Sequence`, it is e.g. `Iterable`. The `Iterable` looks to not be the right choice as I need to use `len()`.

Thank you for recommendations.

```py
# arg1 and arg2 should be one of `list`, `tuple`, `numpy.ndarray` or similar
def fun(arg1: ?, arg2: ?) -> None:
    # assert isinstance(arg1, Sequence-Like), ""
    # assert isinstance(arg12, Sequence-Like), ""
    assert len(arg1) > 0, "length of the arg1 has to be at least 1"
    assert len(arg1) == len(arg2), "..."
```

Comment: Can't you just make a Union of Sequence and np.ndarray?

Comment: and later Union[Sequence, np.ndarray, pandas.Series, or ...]. Hope there is sth more general ;(

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? The question says it needs to support `len`. Your comments on the only answer so far indicate you also need iteration. Anything else? Please edit the question.

Comment: @MattDMo could you leave the answer with recommendation for solution like Union[Sequence, np.ndarray, pandas.Series, or ...]. In my opinion It should be accepted here.

Comment: @Joooeey I added " which will be looped", I could wrongly assumed it is clear.

Comment: @polkas `collections.abc.Collection` appears to be exactly the right fit if these are the only capabilities you require. The docs describe it as "ABC for sized iterable container classes.". Sets and dictionaries will be treated just like lists. In the case of dicitonaries, the values are ignored and only the keys used.

Comment: @Joooeeyone such answer is here and sb can decided to choose the Collection solution. In my opinion the Union solution is better as is more clear and direct. I could not accept the dict for vector-like (1-D) input, I will feel bad with such scenario. BTW I do not have a problem with the set here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward (perhaps hacky) solution is to create a Union specifying the types your function supports:

```
def fun(arg1: Union[Sequence, numpy.ndarray, pandas.Series], arg2: ...
```

You can also pre-define the type so you don't take up so much room in the function signature:

```
SequenceLike = Union[Sequence, numpy.ndarray, pandas.Series]

def fun(arg1: SequenceLike, arg2: SequenceLike) -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: pre-definition seems obvious but is not, thanks for the tip:)

Comment: @polkas you're right. I changed my wording slightly.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do **only** `len` then use `typing.Sized` which means `len`able types.

If you want to support collections with `__iter__`, well, `typing.Collection` adds `__iter__` and `__contains__`, and `ndarray` fulfills that too. But so does a `dict` or a `set`.

---

Beyond that, if you think `list`, `tuple` and `ndarray` are somehow compatible otherwise then you're likely doing a big mess anyway :D There is a very good reason why `ndarray` do not pass for a sequence as it has additional behaviours such as `__reversed__`, `index` and `count`.

Comment: Then should it be typing.Sized and typing.Iterable at the same time. typing.Sized does not mean the input has to be Iterable.

Comment: Well, `typing.Collection` is "iterable sized collections". Fulfills the stuff for `set` too though...

Comment: Example why Sized is wrong: `>>> class test:
...     def __len__():
...         return 10
... 
>>> tt = test()
>>> isinstance(tt, Iterable)
False
>>> isinstance(tt, Sized)
True
>>> [i for i in tt]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'test' object is not iterable`

Comment: " There is a very good reason why ndarray do not pass for a sequence", not agree with that there is a huge discussion on the github issue about this topic and there was not found a consensus. `typing.Collection` is useless as has too broad meaning ...

Comment: @polkas of course there will not be consensus if some people are right and others are wrong.

Comment: Ufff a lot of time was and is burned here  (and others) https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2776, in your opinion:)

Comment: Please consider of leaving a comment in the linked by me github issue. I see you feel confident to help there. Thank you for your contribution here.